# How do i create a table from a json file with multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, datatable

I used this:

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "Bibliothek.json",
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response, "response");
        },
    });
```

to give me a response of my json file which looks this:
https://pastebin.com/2LU5DwRr

What i get back is: [image: example xample]

I want to create a table of each object but i fail in doing so because i never worked with objects before.

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "Bibliothek.json",
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response, "response");
            let lib = response;
            var allarrays = lib.length;
            if (allarrays > 0) {
                var table = document.createElement("table");
                table.style.width = '50%';
                table.setAttribute('border', '1');
                table.setAttribute('cellspacing', '0');
                table.setAttribute('cellpadding', '5');
                var col = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < allarrays; i++) {
                    for (var key in lib[i]) {
                        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                            col.push(key);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        },
    });
```

I understand that my code is not working because the lenght of lib is 1 because it doesnt look into each object.
I just dont know how to access all the objects.

Comment: What is getJSON()? Is it your custom function? You should parse your response like JSON.parse(response.myArray) and your return json should be like {myArray: [ <lot of object and all good things in those>]}. Of cause it depends on case.

Comment: Sorry it was a paste error i put the GETJSON() away.
Also you didn't answer my problem.
I have the data with the multiple objects.
Im just stuck in not understanding how to generate a table from each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nested objects like the one in the pastebin, you can use the inbuilt object methods like Object.keys(), Object.values() and Object.entries() to loop through the response object you are handling.

Comment: Ah this was what i was looking for i guess.
I will read the documentation about it and check if it works.

Comment: How do i get to the key 1 which contains the other arrays o.O ?
I used object entries to get to this but i dont get further.
https://pastebin.com/aUg9cGe6

Comment: When you use Object.entries() on response object, you'll end up with Geraetewelten object and again when you use Object.entries() you'll get the objects inside Geraetewelten. You can use Object.values() on these elements to fetch the object values you are looking for.

Comment: sadly i dont understand, i also tested the values option but it also didnt help me further.

Could u pastebin me an example of what u mean?
Its hard to read here in the comment section

https://pastebin.com/KteJkPYB

Comment: It always stays the same unless i use entries but then it goes out of the object instead of inside.

https://pastebin.com/qqr6cM8s

Comment: I´m gonna make a new question out of this but it already helped me a lot to get closer to the result.